# Does 5HT neccessarily desensitize at long term use of SSRIs?

Tags: neuro-transmitters, drugs, serotonin

I have a knowledge gap which I can't find many papers about.

I know that receptors like 5HT desensitize when a prolonged *increased<sup>1</sup> availability* is present because the brain tries to maintain homeostatic equilibrium. This *might* happen because of the use of SSRIs as

> Presynaptic 5-HT1ARs readily desensitise following exposure to increased 5-HT availability (e.g. through chronic selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors (SSRIs)) but postsynaptic 5-HT1ARs do not
>  <sub>- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5606297/</sub>

Now my question is what happens if SSRIs merely **normalize** a 5HT availability *deficit*? Suppose for whatever reason an individual has less available<sup>2</sup> Serotonin but a *normal*<sup>3</sup> baseline receptor density i.e. a balanced 5HT saturation.

Would 5HT neccesarily downregulate if SSRIs were to increase 5HT availability to a *normal* level needed to maintain homeostatic equilibrium between receptor density and availability?

1 - = higher than normal

2 - e.g. because of insufficient release or production or whatever condition that causes lower than normal availability
3 - not down / up regulated